# Converting memory addresses to gibibytes

Tags: math, processor

A byte-addressable 32-bit computer can address 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 addresses.

Why is it said that it is 4 gibibytes (GiB).

If I have 2^32 addresses, how many bits are them? Is each address 32 bits long too? If so, I can't understand why It is 4 gibibytes, because it would be 2^32 * 32 bits => 2^32 * 32/8 bytes and finally (2^32*32/8)/2^30 gibibytes (taking in count that 1 gibibyte = 2^30 bytes).

Could you explain me how and why could I know that 2^32 addresses are 4 gibibytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our purposes, addresses are 32 bits long. Addresses can assume 2^32 unique values. Each unique address references one byte. If you had a list of all possible addresses, it would have length (32 bits/address) * (2^32 addresses) = 32 * 2^32.

However, you can still only reference 2^32 bytes of memory. 2^32 = 2^2 * 2^30 = 4 * 2^30 bytes. Since 2^30 = Gigabyte, that means 4 Gigabytes.

It looks like your error is in conflating the amount of memory required to hold all 2^32 addresses (which would take 128 GB) and the amount of memory which can be referenced by all 2^32 addresses (which is equal to 2^32 times the addressing unit - we've assumed byte, but if your machine were to work in units of 32 bits instead, you'd be able to reference 16 GB using a 32-bit address space... though all ((usual)) machines use byte-addressable memory, I believe).

Answer (score 1):

With a 32bit address, you have 2^32 addresses of the smallest addressable unit, which is typically a byte; so as 2^10 = 1024, and 2^2 = 4, so basic math says that:

2^32 bytes = 2^2 * 2^10 * 2^10 * 2^10 bytes = 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 bytes

Or, to rewrites that:

4 * 1024 * 1024Kb

Or:

4 * 1024Mb

Or 4Gb